# UIView does not get refreshed after NSLayoutConstraint constant is changed

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, nslayoutconstraint

I want to change UITableView height depending upon user interaction with a button. When user clicks on the button, UITableView gets expanded and click on the same button UITableView height is decreased only to show 1st row. Following is my code

```
    tblFaults?.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()

    if (currentNumber == 1)
    {
        currentNumber = 2
        var newFrame = tblFaults?.frame
        newFrame?.size.height += 67;//tried to change frame as well
        tblFaults?.frame = newFrame!
        faultViewHeight?.constant = 115 
        //faultView height is  tableview height constraint
    }
    else
    {
        currentNumber = 1
        var newFrame = tblFaults?.frame
        newFrame?.size.height -= 67;
        tblFaults?.frame = newFrame!
         faultViewHeight?.constant = 48
    }
    tblFaults?.reloadData()
    //self.view.setNeedsLayout()
    //self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
```

I tried setNeedsDisplay, setNeedsLayout as well as layoutSubviews() after the code. But view does not get refreshed immediately after button click but gets refreshed only after next user interaction (e.g. scrollview change etc)

Comment: You shouldn't be modifying the frame, you need to modify the constraint; show that code

Comment: Don't mix up auto layout and frames.

Comment: Actually I added frame change code as only constarint constant code was not working.I removed it again as per your suggestion and kept this code only

Comment: currentNumber = 2
            //var newFrame = tblFaults?.frame
            //newFrame?.size.height += 67;
            //tblFaults?.frame = newFrame!
            faultViewHeight?.constant = 115 Still its not working :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
  faultViewHeight?.constant = 48
  tblFaults.layoutIfNeeded() // you need to call this method
```

Comment: added tblFaults.layoutIfNeeded() But still does not get refreshed

Comment: try self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.
Actually only constraint constant value change and tableview.reloadData() was enough. The BIG mistake I did was, I was checking the execution on simulator. I tried this on device and it worked perfectly fine. On simulator I was facing the issue even after trying self.view.layoutIfNeeded(). I still do not know why this is the behaviour on simulator and not on device. But eventually app has to run on device and its working there. :) 
Thank you all.